# How to fix Jest error : TypeError: $ is not a function

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I am writing unit test cases for a Vue.js component.

When I am trying to `shallowMount` component using `vue-test-util` I get an error:

> TypeError: $ is not a function at VueComponent.mounted
> (src/components/gridComponent/index.vue:7579:7)

My code:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

global['$'] = global['jQuery'] = $;

import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import gridComponent from '@/components/gridComponent/index'

describe('grid view component', () => {
    it('has the expected HTML structure', async () => {
        let wrapper = await shallowMount(gridComponent, {
            stubs: ['GridLayout', 'GridItem'],
            propsData: {componentsList}
        })
        expect(wrapper.element).toMatchSnapshot()
    })
})
```

Below is the code of gridComponent:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery'

export default {
    name: 'gridComponent',
    components: { GridLayout, GridItem, DxpCommonModal },
    props: ['componentsList'],
    watch: {
        componentsList: function (newVal, oldVal) {
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          this.matchingComponents = this.componentsList
        }
    },
    data () {
        return {
          isDraggable: true,
          isResizable: true
        }
    },
    created () {
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters(['getResources'])
    },
    mounted () {
       $('#headerComponent').html(this.getSelectorHTML(this.siteDetails.header))
       $('#footerComponent').html(this.getSelectorHTML(this.siteDetails.footer))
        this.addHtmlOfComponentsInAPage()
    },
    destroyed () {
    },
    methods: {
        addHtmlOfComponentsInAPage () {
            this.selectedPage.Components.forEach((element, index) => {
                $('#${index}').html(this.getSelectorHTML(this.selectedPage.Components[index]))
            })
        },
        getSelectorHTML (component) {
            const element = document.createElement(component.componentType)
            element.setAttribute('content-id', new Date().getTime().toString())
            if (!this.values && component.demoData) {
                this.values = component.demoData
            }
            if (this.values) {
                this.createMarkup(element, this.values)
                this.values = ''
            }
            return element
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code of the gridComponent?

Comment: I have added code gridComponent

Answer (score 1):

## Troubleshooting

In the component, try

```
const $ = require('jquery')
```

Put this before the usage in the method causing the error.

This will let you know if you are un-defining or redefining  it somewhere.

## Solution 2

You may need jsdom.

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const { window } = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html>`);
const $ = require('jquery')(window);
```

Comment: Put it in right before you use it, not outside the method `mounted`

Comment: And jquery is inside your node_modules folder?

Comment: Do you have a alias for jquery in your configuration?  This may be the solution or the problem...

Comment: I am not sure. Are you talking about to add it in jest configuration?

Comment: Have you also tried `require...` in the root file instead of `import...`?

Comment: Have you tried also installing jsdom?  see updated solution, and note I changed jQuery to jquery

Comment: yes, I have created one setup-jest.js file where added const $ = require('jquery');
global.$ = global.jQuery = $; and then called this file jest config

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input. const $ = require('jquery') worked for me. I have added it in component file.